# Packagemaker for copy files

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I'm making an application and some default files for the entire organization and these files should be copied in the directory `/Users/<username>/Library/MyDirectory/` in every machine. I want to deploy this application and files as an installer package using packagemaker. I tried by dragging the folder containing default files to the and setting destination to `/Library/MyDirectory` but its not creating the directory named `MyDirectory` and copying files to it. I tried by adding a preinstall.sh script with following code to create `MyDirectory`

```
#!/bin/sh

USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${SUDO_USER})
TEMP_DIR="${USER_HOME}/Library/MyDirectory"
mkdir "${TEMP_DIR}"
```

After installing the package `MyDirectory` is creaing but the files not copied to that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch Packagemaker.
Try [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) or [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) with [luggage](https://github.com/unixorn/luggage).

Comment: Packages is so easy to use and have better documentation. Thank you @Michal